# Smoothly increase progress bar while playing audio file

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am playing audio file of different sizes in my application and while audio is playing the progress bar should progress smoothly but progress bar is taking random size steps.

I am using following code :

```
 mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
 mp.setDataSource("audio file path");
 mp.prepare();
 mp.start();
 pb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    while(mp.isPlaying())
                    {
                     publishProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                     pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
                 }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
            }.execute();
```

Is there any way to smoothly increase progressbar?

Comment: Key to smoothly increase progress bar is to increase its value by 1 till audio is playing and do not depend on MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this steps

Step 1:
Get audio duration with `MediaPlayer.getDuration()`

Step 2:
Set ProgressBar progress max. value to value from step 1

Step 3:

Update progress bar periodically from `MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()`, while media playing using Handler.

So the code will be like this

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    final SeekBar mSeelBar = new SeekBar(this);
    final int duration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    final int amountToUpdate = duration / 100;
    Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!(amountToUpdate * mSeelBar.getProgress() >= duration)) {
                        int p = mSeelBar.getProgress();
                        p += 1;
                        mSeelBar.setProgress(p);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }, amountToUpdate);
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17943031/1078003) link for the code

Comment: yeah... thats what I am doing now.. but Progress bar is increasing in steps not smoothly..

Comment: check edited answer that 1 helped me during my implementation

Comment: A better implementation:
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    progressBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
  }
}, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);

Answer (score 2):

Set the Max size of progress bar to a high range... If u set the progress bar to increment between 1  to maximum  100, then rather than using 100 as max use 1000 in place..This is a suggestion from me. Coz i found your code working ok.

Answer (score 2):

This is my mediaplayer creation , just check it out .

```
  public TextView songName,startTimeField,endTimeField;
   private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   private double startTime = 0;
   private double finalTime = 0;
   private Handler myHandler = new Handler();;
   private int forwardTime = 5000; 
   private int backwardTime = 5000;
   private SeekBar seekbar;
   private ImageButton playButton,pauseButton;
   public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      songName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
      startTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      endTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
      playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      pauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
      songName.setText("song.mp3");
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
      seekbar.setClickable(false);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);

   }

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) public void play(View view){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing sound", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mediaPlayer.start();
      finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
      startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
      if(oneTimeOnly == 0){
         seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
         oneTimeOnly = 1;
      } 

      endTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
      );
      startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) startTime)))
      );
      seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
      myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
      playButton.setEnabled(false);
   }

   private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) public void run() {
         startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
         startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
            toMinutes((long) startTime)))
         );
         seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
         myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }
   };
   public void pause(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing sound", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      mediaPlayer.pause();
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
      playButton.setEnabled(true);
   }    
   public void forward(View view){
      int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp+forwardTime)<=finalTime){
         startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Cannot jump forward 5 seconds", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

   }
   public void rewind(View view){
      int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp-backwardTime)>0){
         startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Cannot jump backward 5 seconds",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

   }
```

Comment: As rashmi said, this is wat the way to use progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it smoother by using following logic.

1. Store current value of progress bar and latest progress value as members.
2. Update latter when `onProgressUpdate` method is called.
3. In a timer, put this logic to be executed periodically.

   ```
   if (currentValue < latestProgress) {
       currentValue++;
       pb.setProgress(currentValue);
   }
   ```

   Note that it will slowly march towards it's target value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By printing value of mp.getCurrentPosition in LogCat I found out that the values are not linear.. at some point it stays constant for a while and then jumps randomly.. I have already tried to smooth progress by adding to current progress bar value till getCurrentPosition() returns different value.. but its not working as expected..

Comment: Did you use timer to put time gap in successive addition in current value?

Comment: Separating each update with small time gaps like 50 ms or 200 ms would give you the smoothing effect. Timers are easy to implement, you can have a look at an example here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how

Answer (score 0):

Although the suggestion of using Handler to track the current position of Audio while playing is the only correct way. However, `MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()` not super precise for short audio (saying, about 1 second); and to make life easier I wrote a Utils class to support this purpose by using `CountDownTimer`

**Link demo:** https://github.com/mttdat/utils